# Problema com a altura da imagem

Tags: css, css3

O Banner esquerdo fica assim.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer uma gambiarra, mas não deu muito certo. -> `.slide-1 img{min-height:480px;}`

**Meu código HTML e CSS:**

```css
.slide{width:100%; height:480px; margin-top:40px;}
.slide img{display:block;}
.slide-1{width:60%; float:left;}
.slide-2, .slide-3{width:40%; float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="slide-1">
    <img src="img/img-slide-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div><!--FECHAMENTO DE TAG-->
  <div class="slide-2">
    <img src="img/img-slide-2.jpg" alt="">
  </div><!--FECHAMENTO DE TAG-->
  <div class="slide-3">
    <img src="img/img-slide-3.jpg" alt="">
  </div><!--FECHAMENTO DE TAG-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você colocou as imagens dentro de `div`'s para organizar, então você teria que posicionar primeiro as `div`'s e depois as imagens, veja se isto te ajuda:

```css
.slide{
  width:100%; 
  height:480px; 
  margin-top:40px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 0;
}

.slide img{
  display:inline-block;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-1{
  height:100%;
}

.slide-2, .slide-3{
  height:50%;
}

.coluna-1, .coluna-2{
  display: inline-block;
}

.coluna-1{
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}

.coluna-2{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="coluna-1">
    <img src="http://tvcultura.com.br/upload/tvcultura/programas/programa-imagem-som.jpg" alt="" class="slide-1">
  </div>
  <div class="coluna-2">
    <img src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/imagem/imagem-005.jpg" alt="" class="slide-2">
        <img src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/imagem/imagem-005.jpg" alt="" class="slide-3">
  </div>     
</div>
```

observe que as imagens estão com a propriedade `obeject-fit:cover` o que seria o mesmo efeito do `background-size: cover`

Comment: Vlw, irmão isso me ajudou. Sou iniciante, então eu apanho muito ainda do css.

Answer (score 3):

Se é pra ficar com altura 100% nao é `width:100%`, é `height:100%`, e o outro sentido, "auto".

Se quiser que fique maior que o quadro (ajustando pela largura ou altura, dependendo de qual for menor) precisa usar:

```
background-size:cover
```

em vez de `width` e `height`.

```css
div {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP1X8.png) center;
  background-size:cover;
  /* daqui pra baixo é só para o teste */
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.h {
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}

.v {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="v"></div>
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: Coloquei a altura como 100%, mas não funcionou.

Comment: e pos o "auto" na largura? Na verdade a solução mesmo é o cover.

Comment: Coloquei assim: width:1080px; height:100%;

Comment: bom, sugiro ler com atenção a resposta, isso ai nao tem nada a ver com o que eu respondi. Tente fazer conforme a resposta (tem uma demonstração funcionando, basta clicar em executar). Se nao funcionar conforme respondido, ai vc explica o que deu errado e eu tento ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente está solução rápida, embora não muito eficaz

```
.slide img {width:100%; height:100%;}
```